# Mac validation using python getting empty list

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am validating mac address, Below is the code

```
import re
input = """
        abc
        xyz
        ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        ff::ff::ff::ff::ff::ff
        ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff
        """


regex = re.compile("([A-Fa-f0-9]{2}?-::){5}[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}")
mac_address = re.findall(regex, input)
print(mac_address)
```

actual output:

```
[] # Empty list
```

Expected output:

```
["ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff", "ff::ff::ff::ff::ff::ff", "ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff"]
```

My code explanation:

1) mac address contains alpha numeric that is [A-Fa-f0-9]

2) must contain two characters hence added {2}

3) optional -:: (one colon(:) or two colon(::) or dash) hence added  ?-::

4) option 1,2,3 must matches 5 times hence added {5}

5) at last  [A-Fa-f0-9]{2} must match 2 times

Could any please correct me what i am doing wrong here

Comment: Why are you using a single string instead of a proper list?

Comment: Can please elaborate your question please

Comment: Why isn't `input = ["abc", "xyz", ...]` used instead?

Comment: for testing i am passing string and parsing all matches to list

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the `re.M` flag (for "multi-line" - you've provided a string with multiple lines, so this is necessary). Your regex doesn't parse correctly for me, but my similar regex (five occurrences of "two hex digits followed by either `:`, `::`, or `-`" followed by two more hex digits) works:

```
>>> inp = """
...         abc
...         xyz
...         ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
...         ff::ff::ff::ff::ff::ff
...         ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff
...         """
>>> regex = re.compile(r'(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}(?:\:|\:\:|-)?){5}[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}', flags=re.M)
>>> mac_address = re.findall(regex, inp)
>>> print(mac_address)
['ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff', 'ff::ff::ff::ff::ff::ff', 'ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff']
```

Answer (score 0):

In your pattern your are matching 5 times 2 chars out of `[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}` followed by `-::`

In your example data, the match could be either `::` or `:` or `-`

To match that you could make use of a non capturing group matching either `::` or or one of `:` or `-` using a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and a non capturing [group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) like  `(?:::|[:-])`

**Note** that using `?-::` is not the notation to make for an optional 
character.

If you want to make all of the options optional, you can make the group optional `(?:::|[:-])?` (which would possibly also match `ffffffffffff` but is not in the example data)

```
\b(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}(?:::|[:-])){5}[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/q1zNtJ/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/DXkYQL)

For example

```
import re
input = """
        abc
        xyz
        ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        ff::ff::ff::ff::ff::ff
        ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff
        """


regex = re.compile(r"\b(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}(?:::|[:-])){5}[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}\b")
mac_address = re.findall(regex, input)
```

Output

```
['ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff', 'ff::ff::ff::ff::ff::ff', 'ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff']
```